# Rudin's Proof of Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-explanation, compactness

> (a) If $\{P_n\}$ is a sequence in a compact metric space $X$, then some sub­sequence of $\{P_n\}$ converges to a point of $X$.
>   (b) Every bounded sequence in $\mathbb R^k$ contains a convergent subsequence.

Rudin proves (a), then argues for (b) as follows:

"(b) This follows from (a), since Theorem 2.41 implies that every bounded subset of $\mathbb R^k$ lies in a compact subset of $\mathbb R^k$," where Theorem 2.41 is the Heine-Borel Theorem.

But doesn't this require the set to be bounded AND closed? From what I can see Rudin makes no argument about that the sequence in $\mathbb R^k$ is closed.

Comment: See [this introduction to posting mathematical notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Thank you. Will check this out

Comment: PLease see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He is not saying that the bounded set itself is compact. What he is saying is that that bounded set is **contained** in some compact set. As a bounded set is, by definition, contained in an open ball, it is also contained in the closure of the ball, which is compact.

Answer (score 2):

Note than (a) asks only that the sequence is "in a compact metric space".  So it doesn't require the sequence to be a closed set, only that it be contained in a compact set.  The points in $\mathbb R^k$ with norm $\le M$ are a closed and bounded (ergo compact) subset of $\mathbb R^k$.